# Embed SQL Server Query in Excel Workbook

Tags: c#, excel

I know how to use code to import an access query into an Excel workbook, but how would I embed a SQL Server query into an excel worksheet.  The steps to manually do such would be to click the Data Tab, From Other Sources, From SQL Server and imput the server name then next choose your table then click finish.  Then click properties, definition tab, command type is SQL and the command text is the sql syntax you want to run.  Then Okay, Okay and Okay.  I can not figure out how to replicate this process in C#, can someone please assist me with this?!

EDIT --
Sorry I should have posted the code I was working on...but anywho here it is.  Throws a peculiar message I have not seen before...

```
QueryTables oTables;
QueryTable oTable;
Range oRng;
Sheets oSheets;
Excel._Workbook oWB;
Excel._Worksheet oWS;
Excel.Application oXL
try
{
  oSheets = oWB.Sheets;
  oWS = (Excel._Worksheet)(oWB.ActiveSheet);
  oRng = Global.Variables.GlobalVariables.oWS.get_Range("A1");
  oTables = oWS.QueryTables;
  object aStrSQL = "SELECT * FROM dbo.tableproductInfo;
  object connection = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";;
  oTable = oTables.Add(connection, oRng, aStrSQL);
  oTable.RefreshStyle = XlCellInsertionMode.xlInsertEntireRows;
  oTable.Refresh(true);
  oXL.UserControl = true;
}
catch (Exception e) { MessageBox.Show(e.ToString()); }
```

EDIT --- The issue takes place when the code reaches

```
oTable = oTables.Add(connection, oRng, aStrSQL);
```

Message displayed is:
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException(0x800A03EC) Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(string memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, messageData& msgData) at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.QueryTables.Add(Object Connection, Range, Destination, Object Sql)

EDIT ---
Adding provider for OLEDB produces this[image]

Comment: @Mike - that is what I did.  Having issues converting it to C# - I just realized my code didn't copy in in my initial post, but I have updated it now.

Comment: So it looks like there's an issue when the `QueryTables.Add()` method is invoked. Perhaps there is an issue with the parameters. Have you tried to append `ODBC;` or `OLEDB;` to the beginning of the connection string? See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837764.aspx) for proper formatting of the connection string.

Comment: @Mike if I add OleDB it errors (different error) on the refresh if I add ODBC it pops up asking me for the data source on the refresh statement? --- OLEDB throws the error of System.Runtime.InteropServices; Initialiation of the data source failed.

Comment: Well, I gave it the ol' college try. Consider comparing your code (and connection string) with [this working example from a MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2010/08/05/how-to-programmatically-add-a-querytable-and-data-connection-to-excel.aspx). (Also, to reduce clutter in this comments area, I deleted a few previous comments that resulted in updates to your question.)

Comment: @MasterOfStupidQuestions Did you resolve the issue? I am also facing exactly the same issue? Please reply.